# How to express subset relation in Coq?

Tags: coq, set-theory

How can I describe in Coq that one set `Y` is a subset of another set `X`?

I tested the following:

```
Definition subset (Y X:Set) : Prop :=
  forall y:Y, y:X.
```

, trying to express that if an element `y` is in `Y`, then `y` is in `X`. But this generates type errors about `y`, not surprisingly.

Is there an easy way to define `subset` in Coq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how it is done in the standard library (`Coq.Logic.ClassicalChoice`):

```
Definition subset (U:Type) (P Q:U->Prop) : Prop := forall x, P x -> Q x.
```

Unary predicates `P` and `Q` represent some subsets of the (universal) set `U`, so the above definition reads: whenever some `x` is in `P`, it is in `Q` at the same time.

A somewhat similar defintion can be found in `Coq.MSets.MSetInterface`:

```
Definition Subset s s' := forall a : elt, In a s -> In a s'.
```

where `In` has type `elt -> t -> Prop`, which means that some element of type `elt` is a member of a set of type `t`.